# LDAP-Google Apps exclusion list

Tags: ldap, openldap, g-suite

I'm trying to set-up synchronization between my OpenLDAP server and Google Apps. There are some users accounts already created in Google Apps which are not in my OpenLDAP server. That accounts are suspend every time, when I perform synchronization. According to GADS documentation it's possible to create exclusion list which contains user's account that shouldn't be synchronized. But as I've understood from the documentation exclusion lists should contain only local LDAP user accounts than shouldn't be synchronized with .
Am I wrong or is there any solution for this situation?

Comment: Not to sound mean, but you asked -- you are wrong. :) There are exclusion rules for both the LDAP and Google Apps sides. If you update your question with some more detail, I can probably assist you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In GADS, there are sections to both ignore AD accounts (do not create Google Apps Accounts), and ignore Google Apps accounts that don't have a corresponding AD account.  I used this second section to protect administrator and other important accounts from accidental deletion.  Keep fishing around in the settings and you'll find it.

The setting is found in the Google Apps Configuration section. [Here is a link](http://www.google.com/support/enterprise/static/gapps/docs/admin/en/gads/admin/config_ga_settings_excl.html#1146243) in the manual.

Google Apps Exclusion Rules:
[image]

AD User Exclusion Rules:
[image]

Comment: You may even create OUs in Google Apps to store your "special" users out of scope of normal user policy.

Comment: I've checked it one more time and haven't fount section to exclude Google Apps users ) On "User Accounts" tab there is a section called "Exclusion Rules", but GADS Admin guide says that there I may exclude "Internal users who do not have outside email addresses; Printers, conference rooms, and other non-user resources; Test users on your LDAP directory server; Users who do not want a Google Apps mailbox". But there is no mention about my Google Apps user, that already exist. I've tried to specify Google Apps users there, but they still became suspended after synchronization process.

Comment: Here's the link to the section http://www.google.com/support/enterprise/static/gapps/docs/admin/en/gads/admin/config_ga_settings_excl.html. It's in the Google Apps Configuration section

Comment: I've missed first tab due to my inattention. Thank you very match!